# Can I use different data connections together in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sqldatasource

Is it possible to use two or more data connections in Visual Studio and use them in a single query, like we can do in SQL server management Studio (while we use MySQL and MSSQL at the same time)?

E.g.

```
SELECT * INTO testMySQL.dbo.shoutbox
FROM openquery(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM tigerdb.shoutbox')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL, then you can use Microsoft SQL Server Linked Server to accomplish this. A Linked Server is a server linked via OLEDB. This linked server will allow you to connect to the MySQL database from SQL Server and run remote queries.

Example

```
SELECT * from MyLinkedServer.[Database].[Schema].TableName  T1
INNER JOIN MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([NameOfLinkedSERVER], 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME') T1
INNER JOIN MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK
```

Comment: But you'd still be firing this query at one dataconnection, wouldn't you? (I'm learning here, so your answer is good either way).

Comment: Yes it would only be one dataconnection in your application but this one data connection will allow you to execute remote queries on the MYSQL Server.

Comment: Dear Hartsock,
Your query was useful, but still is not solving my issue in query builder of visual studio, where I have 2 different data connections:
1.mysql connection named as dimAccess
2.mssql server connection named as te-sharepoint\sqlexpress.dimAccess.dbo
Now I want to select data from these 2 connections in a single select query and the query below is my case:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQLDIMACCESS, 'SELECT * FROM tb_user) T1
INNER JOIN te-sharepoint\sqlexpress.dimAccess.dbo.tblUserProfileT2 ON T1.id = T2.iEmpID
This query is having correct result only in SqlServerManagement,butNotInVS

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hartsock ...
I found the solution based on your examples... My only mistake was related to bad naming of data connections, using by default special characters, like '-' or '\' ... anyway...good experience...thank once again...

Comment: Dear Hartsock,

I have another issue related to this openquery closure:
How can I use a parameter inside sql openquery, such as:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([NameOfLinkedSERVER], 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where field1=@someParameter') T1
INNER JOIN MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK

Answer (score 0):

No (AFAIK). But you could perhaps deconstruct the connectionstring from your web.config to get the db location, and re-create your sql (in a SP) from there?

Comment: Firstly thank you for your effort! Something I've understood, but the way I should do, still I need more details, please...
please, can you explain or give me any example, like step by step :) ...

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355472/using-the-web-config-to-set-up-my-sql-database-connection-string