# ASP.NET Database options

Tags: asp.net, datasource

Apparently no one connects visual web dev express to databases because I can't find anything helpful on google.

1. Do I need to connect a datasource to my project, for the login control/etc to work? If not, how else?
2. What (free!) databases can I use as a data source in visual web dev express?
3. How do I connect them?

My question is a little short but I have to go, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here [Using the Web.Config to set up my SQL database connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355472/using-the-web-config-to-set-up-my-sql-database-connection-string)

Thats all you need!

**UPDATE**

A little example: 
First add the reference System.Configuration to your project then Imports in your code (using System.Configuration).

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //Create a DataSet
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString; //ConnectionString from web.config
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); //Create a new SqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = ConectionString; //Connect using your ConnectionString
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Your SQL query goes here", con); //Get Data
da.Fill(ds); //Fill a DataSet (in this case)
con.Close(); //Close connection
```

Comment: Ok, I have a connection string, but what do I do with it? I've added it under web.config <configuration><connectionStrings>, but how do I tell VWD to use and connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the built in Membership features of ASP.NET use a database to store their information.
2. Sticking with Microsoft for the DB?

   SQL Server Express:
   http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

   SQL Server Compact 4.0:
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2
3. Depends how you perform data access, but you'll start by constructing a connection string.